# How to remove/hide Google Maps Search Icon when zooming out?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

The autofill search function is working great on my map and zooms into the searched address and places a custom pin centered, however the pin stays there at all zoom levels. My goal is to have the pin remove/hide when the user zooms back out past level 18 zoom. My guess is that an google.maps.event.addListener with 'zoom_changed' might work but I have no idea where or how to place it within this code. Thank you for any help in advance.

```
    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
      searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    var markersS = [];
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and        
    // retrieve more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
      var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

      if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
      }

      // Clear out the old markersS.
      markersS.forEach(function(marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
      });
      markersS = [];

      // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      places.forEach(function(place) {
        if (!place.geometry) {
          console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
          return;
        }
        var icon = {
          url: '.../HOME.png',
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(41.5, 64),
        };

       // Create a marker for each place and also set Zoom Condition.
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
        var zoomS = map.getZoom();
        if (zoomS>=18) {
            markersS.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: icon,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location,
            //animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            }));
          }
        else if (zoomS<18) {
            markersS.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
            });
            markersS = [];
          }
        });

        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          // Only geocodes have viewport.
          bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
      });
      map.fitBounds(bounds);

    });
```

Comment: Everything works great now with the added IF, IF ELSE functions however now when I search a new address, a home icon marks the new spot but the old searched home icon still remains, showing two icons, this continues onward. Is there anything I can add to the code that will remove the previous searched icon and only load the new/current one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zoom is in your initMap function. Just use a conditional statement.

Comment: Just figured it out; added an if, else if function and it worked to the code below and it worked! markersS.push(new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          icon: icon,
          title: place.name,
          position: place.geometry.location,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        }));

Comment: You've got it. :)

Comment: thanks twill! i updated the code above which works; however a new issue has arisen, if you search a new address, the old icon still remains. Am I missing a step that removes it entirely when a new address is searched?